# C - sscanf() %d picking up zero and causing destination &curritem.stock to be NULL

Tags: c, scanf

sscanf() is great for the problem i'm facing, but it's doing something unexpected.

tmp is a line read in from a file, i need to parse out parts of the line into separate pieces of data. curritem is a struct with int dollar, int cent, cat[], int stock, and int history[].

The odd issue i'm having is that when %d picks up a double zero (00), it appropriately inserts integer zero into destination, but upon confronting a single zero (0), the integer is not added appropriately to the destination; for example, while collecting data pertaining to history[], all is well, adding 1, 4, 8, 2, 13, etc. to the array, but a single zero cuts everything off there, as if NULL terminated at that point, which i presume is related.

The code:

```
sscanf(tmp, "%d.%d%s %d %d %d", &curritem.dollar, &curritem.cent, 
       curritem.cat, &curritem.stock, &curritem.history[0],
       &curritem.history[1]);
```

I have left out some indices of curritem.history[], as it clutters the necessary information.

Example of what i should get, if all integers were added correctly:

```
curritem.history[0...11] = 5 2 6 1 0 11 9 0 15 0 7 10
```

What actually results as of right now:

```
curritem.history[0...11] = 5 2 6 1
```

Something dies when sscanf() sees a single '0' via %d and adds that to &struct.intarray[n]

Any ideas?

Try not to recommend an entirely different solution to my general program function, sscanf() is working wonders in every other aspect.

Thank you for your time!

EDIT:

A snippet of exact input:

WL162343Fleece-Lined Double L Jeans     49.95PANTS  3  8  1  0  1  0  7  1  5  2 10  2  6

All information is acquired successfully until after the category- in this case, 'PANTS'.

With this example, my int array called history should hold the values

```
3  8  1  0  1  0  7  1  5  2 10  2  6
```

But upon printing every item in the array:

```
int n = 0;
for (n = 0; curritem.history[n]; n++) {
  printf("%i ", curritem.history[n]);
}
```

The following output results:

```
3  8  1
```

EDIT:

The 'for' loop used for printing is incapable of distinguishing between an integer '0' and a null-termination of the array. Annoying.

Comment: Your description of behaviour doesn't make any sense. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with the exact input you supply to the program, and the output that you get

Comment: We'd need to see more of your code (and some input data wouldn't hurt).  How are you displaying `curritem.history`?  Do you use any other functions with it between `sscanf()` and checking the contents?

Comment: Maybe i provided too much, such that it's being over-thought. The issue is simple; sscanf() takes a line from a file, and rather than placing the detected '0' (via %d, this detects integers) integer into an array index, it appears to be NULL-terminating the array at that point. I cannot provide the exact input and output because there is far too much, and the output isn't actually a necessary part of the program (simply a method of visualizing the problem). 

I have edited the original post with more information.

Comment: Really?? I was under the impression that format will result in printing every item in an array until termination- this would imply the array is terminated prematurely; if that is not the case, then, is there no distinguishable difference between the termination of the array and a zero entry?

Comment: There's no "null terminator" for arrays in general, even `char` arrays.  By convention, a `char` with a value of `0` is used to mark the end of strings (but not the array that holds them) since text won't normally contain any such characters, and many string functions follow that convention -- but otherwise `0` can appear legitimately in an array, even an array of `char`.

Comment: `WL162343Fleece-Lined` will not match `%d` in sscanf either. I guess you mucked that up.  In any case you should *always* check the return value of `sscanf` to see that the expected number of elements were read.

Answer (score 2):

What do you think that `curritem.history[n]` will return in the `for`'s condition when it contains zero?

Comment: Zero. Because the integer zero is at that position in my integer array. Are you implying this type of loop simply cannot be used with integer arrays containing zero; an equivalent statement to "an integer array including a value of zero has no distinguishable termination point"? That seems downright silly.

Comment: In any case I would find it much safer and more transparent to explicitly reference the length of the array (even if there was an option to do this implicitly).

Comment: @CoshCaust Yes, and zero is false. Integer array with zeros can have a distinguishable termination point, you just need to define one. Eg. negative numbers.

Comment: @CoshCaust all arrays have a "termination point": the end of the array

Comment: @MattMcNabb From my understanding, there is no 'end of the array' in C; nothing is stopping you from continuing past the originally declared size's max index.
StenSoft, This makes sense (a bit contrary to Matt) given C's nature.

Comment: @CoshCaust there is an end. If the array has 12 elements then the end comes after the 12th element (index 11).  You can write code that attempts to read past the end of the array; then you are no longer reading the array.